# jQuery plug-in to remap numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery plug-in to remap the "dot" key in the numeric keypad? The purpose is to make it print a decimal separator, rather than a dot, in languages that use commas or other characters. I'd like to mimic the behaviour of some desktop applications like MS Excel.

(It's okay to hard-code the output character.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this jQuery plugin you can configure what character to use for the numpad decimal separator.

[NumpadDecSeparator](http://nuyensgert.be/projects/numpad-decimal-separator/)

Comment: Great young project. It does all I had in mind with some extra bits (the `toLocaleString` trick to find out regional settings is witty) and the code is nicely written. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a plugin, you can bind to every input element a function that replace dot with comma or other character on keyup event.

```
$(":input")​.bind({
    "keyup" : function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode==110) {
            e.currentTarget.value = e.currentTarget.value.replace(/\./g,",")
        }
    }
    })​
```

Comment: Probably it is even more correct to replace only last dot char.

Comment: I'm willing to write my own code, but only if there isn't a plug-in already because it's not as easy at it appears. Your sample code, for instance, prevents normal text edition: it moves the caret to the end of the text.

Comment: It appears that there isn't such plug-in so I'm accepting your answer as the closest one. I've started working in my own plug-in.

Comment: See Eduardo Molteni's answer: they finally wrote such plug-in.